# No resource found that matches the given name - androidSDK, Eclipse, javaFXports

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've spent all day looking at the various problems/solutions on Stackoverflow for this issue and I have not been able to track my particular issue down.  I have tried:

- verifying resource locations;
- drawable vs. mipmap for icon resources;
- making sure resources are in the res/drawable, res/mipmap or res/values folder
  (and yes, my strings.xml does have the string resource in it that is not being found) ;)
- verifying sourcesets in gradle.build;
- cleaning project and removing the build folder;
- exporting the project, removing it from the Eclipse workspace altogether and re-importing the project;
- building with --debug to try to get more information on the issue;
- any other suggestion found in any other post, regardless of how ridiculous it sounded ;)

I am new to both android development and gradle, but I am not new to Java or Eclipse.

If I remove all references to external resources from the Androidmanifest.xml file, the project builds, installs and runs successfully on my connect device with no warnings.

I am using FMXL and a css for styles and those resources are found and used successfully during the build process, so I am almost certain that the android resources that are required at runtime are not being found in the specified resource folder for some reason.

I hoping some of you more seasoned android developers see something I'm obviously doing wrong.

Perhaps I'm missing something in the jfxmobile { android {} } section of build.gradle?

Here are the relevant files - if you want anything else, don't hesitate to ask:

## build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src/java"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/res"
        }
    }
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        targetSdkVersion = 23
        minSdkVersion = 17
        applicationPackage = 'com.mkdaws32.testapp'
    }
}


mainClassName = 'com.mkdaws32.testapp.Main'
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mkdaws32.testapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.9">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
    <application  android:label="@string/title" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="@string/title" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.mkdaws32.testapp.Main"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Test FXML App</string>
</resources>
```

## Screenshot of Project Folders

[Eclipse project folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgJaz.png)

## Build Errors

```
:processAndroidResourcesDebugC:\Users\Kent\workspace\TestJavaFXPorts3\build\javafxports\tmp\android\AndroidManifest.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title').

C:\Users\Kent\workspace\TestJavaFXPorts3\build\javafxports\tmp\android\AndroidManifest.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

C:\Users\Kent\workspace\TestJavaFXPorts3\build\javafxports\tmp\android\AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title').
```

Thanks so much in advance!  I have found this to be an overwhelmingly useful resource, just browsing the established Q's and A's

Comment: Looks like I will be re-installing the tools on my main dev machine from scratch... *sigh*  This javaFXports/Eclipse environment seems awfully unstable - I might just move to Android Studio for Android and XCode for IOS - most of the code will still be common.  Sucks because I've been using Eclipse for 12 years or so for Java server development and I really like it.

Comment: Switching to Jetbrains products is a breath of fresh air

Comment: Yeah - they look really good, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like an "environment" problem.  I was able to duplicate the project from scratch on another machine in another workspace and it appears to work fine there...  The only difference that I can see is that the machine it was failing on was WIN64 and the one I got it working on was WIN32.